# Why is $ \mathcal{m}$ principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is $ \mathcal{m}$ principal ?

Given $ \mathcal{m}$ is the maximal ideal of a ring $A$ then with $k=A/ \mathcal{m}$ if one has $\dim_k(\mathcal{m}/\mathcal{m^2})=1$ then $\mathcal{m}$ is principal. I don't know whether it is relevant but the ring was assumed to be local artinian, or does it hold universally provided it has finitely many generators ?

So it has finitely many generators, if there were 2 or more how would that make the dimension higher ?

Comment: hint: use Nakayama's lemma

Comment: Is this just Krull's principal ideal theorem? Since $\dim A \leq \dim_k(m/m^2) = 1$ (by the dimension theorem), the height of any prime ideal is at most 1 and so is generated by at most 1 element.

Comment: @cat it's possible to have prime ideals of height $1$, indeed even of height $0$, that are not principal, even in a local artinian ring. eg look at $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$

Comment: @cat, Atticus Stonestrom I saw that in a video here at 59min05sec https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnZEa-I4hxQ&t=59m05s

Comment: @rsnmrtn have you tried using Nakayama's lemma? it is the easiest way to prove this

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom thank you for that! @ rsnmrtn if you have Atiyah/MacDonald, this is mentioned in Proposition 8.8 in the section on Artin rings.